# How To loop active class in wordpress for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type named Homedocs. i want to highlight the particular selection when the thumbnail is selected.as follows:[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="tab-content">
                  <?php
                    foreach ($homedoc as $doc) {
                    ?>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="<?php echo $doc->ID;?> ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                               <img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($doc->ID) ); ?>" alt=""> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="dr-details">
                                    <h2 class="mb0"><?php echo $doc->post_title;?></h2>
                                    <h4 class="mb25"><?php echo get_post_meta($doc->ID,'Department',true);?></h4>                                    
                                    <p><?php echo $doc->post_content;?></p>

                                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default mr10">make appoinment</a> <a href="doctor-details.html" class="btn btn-primary">View all</a>                                    
                                   <div class="dr-social-box">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                   </div>                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>

                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="dr-tabs-box"> 
                  <!-- Nav tabs -->
                  <ul class="nav dr-tab" role="tablist">
                  <?php 
                  foreach ($homedoc as $doc) {
                  ?>
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="<?php echo $doc->ID; ?>" aria-controls="dr1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <div class="dr-box">
                        <span class="dr-img"><img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($doc->ID) ); ?>" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="" /></span>
                        <span class="dr-title"><?php echo $doc->post_title;?></span>
                        <span class="dr-sub-title"><?php echo get_post_meta($doc->ID,'Department',true);?></span>                    
                    </div> 
                    </a></li>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                  </ul>
                </div>      
            </div>
```

But i am failing to make only one tab active at a time and am ending up with the following result:[image]

can anyone please xplain how to make a tab active in a loop and make it only display when thumbnail is clicked

Comment: post your jquery script